# What's a distribution with an abyss instead of a peak?

Tags: density-function, uniform-distribution, continuous-data

I am looking for a (commonly used) probability density function, which would look like a normal distribution flipped upside down. It would look like a uniform distribution with a dent in the middle.

Just to be clear, I am dealing with a continuous random variable within some range, say `[-1,1]`.

Sometimes I have data which is concentrated around zero, but other times I have data which is concentrated toward 1 and -1, while the region around zero is relatively underpopulated.
Is there a kind of pdf which (depending on some parameter) can represent these two cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beta distribution? You'd have to rescale your [-1,1] into [0,1].

[image]

Don't know if this will get the level of weight you want into the corners. Decreasing the shape parameters forces more weight to them though.

Comment: Actually, the shape parameters are the exact parameters I need to adjust to fit both cases I mentioned. It looks like this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: The beta distribution illustrated above has an **antimode** at $x =  0.5$. This kind of minor terminology polarises people all the way from "yet another term we don't really need" to "just the term I was looking for".

Comment: Well, the term is certainly better than 'abyss'!